# format arabic text with english characters in excel

Tags: php, phpexcel, right-to-left

I have a webpage for displaying the survey.The survey answers contains arabic letters which means arabic translation follows each answer,then a `': symbol'`.,then a graph,the percentage of votes for that answer and total number of votes inside () bracket.

Screen shot of webpage:[image: webpage]

I want to need to export this page to excel.I have done that,but an issue occurs while displaying the result like this[image: excelimage]

That is survey answers comes under the Answers by percentage block.As you can see, the survey answer comes in this order, that is survey question in English followed by the percent votes and the column symbol, then the Arabic translation and finally the `% symbol`. I understood this comes because the Arabic letters are from right to left.I need to display properly just like the way it got displayed in webpage.I have done many things like putting direction style ,but it didn't work for me. My php code is like this:

```
$ans .= '( '.$getAns[2] . ': '. round((($getTotalAnsCountStr > 0)?
 (($getAnsCountStr * 100) / $getTotalAnsCountStr):'0'),2) . '% ) ';

//$getAns[2] is for each survey answer  
//$getTotalAnsCountStr for total anwers in this survey answer
//$getAnsCountStr for total votes for this particular answer
```

Comment: So how are you actually creating your Excel file? What library are you using?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have used php-excel class downloaded from github

Comment: You mean [this one](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel)? or [this one](https://github.com/oliverschwarz/php-excel)

Comment: @MarkBaker no..this link ..http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

Comment: @MarkBaker author is Oliver Schwarz <oliver.schwarz@gmail.com>

Comment: In that case, the answer is simple: you can't convert a cell to rtl using that library: it is written as a very simple library with limited capabilities and formatting

Comment: @MarkBaker I have used your PHPxcel library from github.I couldnt find a solution for this issue.Rest everythng works fine .Pls help me

Comment: @MarkBaker I have seen $objWorksheet->setRightToLeft(false);,its not working

Comment: `$objWorksheet->setRightToLeft()` determines the order of columns (right to left or left to right), not the order of text in a cell

Comment: If `$objWorksheet->setRightToLeft()` isn't working, which writer are you using? I've just tested it successfully for both Excel2007 and Excel5 Writers, which are the only writers that it's implemented for

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to change the order of text inside the cell,how can I do that.I am using phpExcel from https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Currently, PHPExcel only supports rtl for worksheets, not for individual cells: I'll try taking a look to see what code changes it will take

Comment: The develop branch of PHPExcel on github now supports setting text readorder for individual cells using `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C3')->getAlignment()->setReadorder(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::READORDER_RTL);` but currently only for the Excel2007 Reader and Writer